# Exclude Checkbox from anchor HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

In my web application, I need an html list of links with a checkbox in front of each. I need to make the list so that a user can click on anywhere on the `<li>` other than only on the text to visit the link. But I need the checkbox to be excluded from the link and be checked/unchecked independently so that clicking on the checkbox does not make the link click.

[image]

For my purpose I created the markup as follows:

```
<a href='projecthome.php?pid=1'>
<li>
<input type='checkbox' name='chkproject' value='project'/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Example
</li>
</a>
```

This works perfectly in Chrome and I can check/uncheck the checkbox without triggering link click. But in firefox, when I click on the checkbox, link click triggers and browser directs to the link. How can I prevent this? Is there any other alternative way other than my html markup to prevent this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with James but failing that you can accomplish by using the property:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Comment: This will not work in IE8, 9 or 10, which collectively make up around 35% of internet users.

Answer (score 1):

The `li` element may only be a child of a `ul` or `ol` element, not an `a` element.

I don't actually know what you're trying to achieve with your current markup, but I'd suggest instead using:

```
<a href='projecthome.php?pid=1'>...</a>
<label>
    <input type='checkbox' name='chkproject' value='project'/>
    Example
</label>
```

Also you shouldn't use `&nbsp;` to space out your elements, you should use CSS:

```css
label input[type="checkbox"] {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice advices @James. I removed &nbsp and added css.

Comment: @Deepal no worries. It's probably worth noting that the answer you've accepted will not work in IE8, 9 or 10. http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events

Comment: Thank you for the information @James. I did not needed to add the above code for IE9. It works by default as in chrome.

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>testing</title>
</head>
<style>
li{width:100%; margin-bottom:5px;float:left;}
div{width:100%;}
li a{width:98%;padding:10px 0px 10px 30px; float:left; position:relative;}
</style>
<body>
<li>
<div style="background-color:#CCCCCC; float:left; position:relative;">
<a href="projecthome.php?pid=1" target="_blank">This is your link</a>
<input type='checkbox' name='chkproject' value='project' style="position:relative; clear:both;z-index:10; margin-left:10px; float:left; margin-top:-25px;"/>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div style="background-color:#CCCCCC; float:left; position:relative;">
<a href="projecthome.php?pid=1" target="_blank">This is your link 2</a>
<input type='checkbox' name='chkproject' value='project' style="position:relative; clear:both;z-index:10; margin-left:10px; float:left; margin-top:-25px;"/>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div style="background-color:#CCCCCC; float:left; position:relative;">
<a href="projecthome.php?pid=1" target="_blank">This is your link 3</a>
<input type='checkbox' name='chkproject' value='project' style="position:relative; clear:both;z-index:10; margin-left:10px; float:left; margin-top:-25px;"/>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div style="background-color:#CCCCCC; float:left; position:relative;">
<a href="projecthome.php?pid=1" target="_blank">This is your link 4</a>
<input type='checkbox' name='chkproject' value='project' style="position:relative; clear:both;z-index:10; margin-left:10px; float:left; margin-top:-25px;"/>
</div>
</li>
</body>
</html>
```